# Remove duplicates from ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I have an arraylist,i want to remove the duplicates with respect to the productId(14 and 1)that added lastly.I tried this but am geting error.

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for (HashMap<String, String> list: modelData.displaylist) {
    set.addAll ((Collection<? extends String>) list);
}
ArrayList<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>(set);
Log.e("uniqueList", "" + uniqueList);
```

The output i wanted this only.

```
 (2 = {HashMap@4692}  size = 4 and 7 = {HashMap@4692}  size = 4 )
```

my arraylist is below

```
displaylist = {ArrayList@4652}  size = 10
0 = {HashMap@4633}  size = 4
0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5037} "spQuantity" -> "1"
1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5038} "prdName" -> "Aqua"
2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5039} "proprice" -> "20"
3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5040} "productId" -> "14"

1 = {HashMap@4692}  size = 4
0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5031} "spQuantity" -> "6"
1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5032} "prdName" -> "RailNeer"
2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5033} "proprice" -> "22"
3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5034} "productId" -> "1"

2 = {HashMap@4715}  size = 4
0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5022} "spQuantity" -> "1"
2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5024} "proprice" -> "20"
1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5023} "prdName" -> "RailNeer"
3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5025} "productId" -> "1"


3 = {HashMap@4715}  size = 4
0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5009} "spQuantity" -> "8"
1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5010} "prdName" -> "Aqua"
2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5011} "proprice" -> "20"
3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@5012} "productId" -> "14"


6 = {HashMap@4893}  size = 4
0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4985} "spQuantity" -> "6"
1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4986} "prdName" -> "Aqua"
2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4987} "proprice" -> "20"
3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4988} "productId" -> "14"

7 = {HashMap@4909}  size = 4
0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4972} "spQuantity" -> "9"
1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4973} "prdName" -> "Aqua"
2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4974} "proprice" -> "20"
3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4975} "productId" -> "14"
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the error?

Comment: @valrauko am getting error -java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.Collection

Comment: You have this `HashMap<String, String> list` and this `(Collection<? extends String>) list` ... how can this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that I notice from your question, the first thing is that you are trying to cast the hash map as a collection (which can't be). If you want to have a unique set of the hashmaps then you can simply do:

```
Set<HashMap<String, String>> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
set.addAll(modelData.displaylist) 
ArrayList<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>(set);
```

But notice that the set uniqueness will be from the hashmap instances and not their content. Which leads to the second thing that I can notice. After reading the original list, it seems that you have a list of products where each product is repeated but the product's have different quantities and prices (probably the price is a mistake). So I think that what you want to do is iterate the original list and add the product to a list if it does not exists or update the product quantity if the product was already there, you can accomplish that by using a list and iterate the list to know if the product is already there

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> uniqueList = new ArrayList();
for (HashMap<String, String> prod: modelData.displaylist) {
    HashMap<String, String> foundProd = null;
    for (HashMap<String, String> uniqueProd: uniqueList) {
       if (uniqueProd.get("productId").equals(prod.get("productId")) {
          foundProd = uniqueProd; 
          break;
       }
    }
    if (foundProd == null) {
       uniqueList.add(prod);
    } else {
       // Do something if the product already existed (maybe update qty)
    }
}
Log.e("uniqueList", "" + uniqueList);
```

**Update**

To get the last element from the list, you can use the same code but walk through the list in reverse order (last items first):

```
for (int i = modelData.displayList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   final HashMap<String, String> prod = (HashMap<String, String) modelData.displayList.get(i);
   ...
}
```

Or you can use a hashmap instead of conditionally insert the elements on the list and then create a list with the hashmap values:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (HashMap<String, String> prod: modelData.displaylist) {
    // Always override 
    tempMap.put(prod.get("productId"), prod);
}
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> uniqueList = new ArrayList(tempMap.values());
Log.e("uniqueList", "" + uniqueList);
```

Comment: Thank you very much..but am getting only the first insertion of the displaylist.I want the last insertion list

Comment: I worked out your updated answer, am getting only the last insertion of one product.I wanted last inserted products with respect to the Product Id.

Comment: for eg:in my displaylist productId 14 and 1.just want to get the last all product id insertion list.

Comment: Which version did you implemented, can you make an update to your question with the new code?